# spread operation (three dot) in javascript being blocked by vscode intelisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

Visual studio code intellisense is blocking dot dot dot `{...}` spread operator by popping up and **autocompleting** with keywords in between the dots like `{.Array.Array.Array}`.
This is really annoying since you can no longer spread objects and arrays fast. You will have to press `esc` in between to close the popup.

Trying to type

[image: three dot spread operation]

gets blocked by intellisense to result in

[image: visual studio code Intellisense blocking spread operation, three dot not working in vscode]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually disable this annoying problem in the settings:

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (control + comma)
- Type `editor.suggest.showWords` in the search box
- `Uncheck` the Setting,  (It says `When enabled intellisense shows text-suggestions`)

**Or you can disable it only for javascript wit this:**

- Open settings.json by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, and typing `settings.json`
- Add the line `"editor.suggest.showWords": false` in `settings.json`, inside the `[javascript]` section.

For more information on this fix, you can check [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130096) github issue on the official vscode repo.